# Make find succeed even if there are no matching files

Tags: bash, shell-scripting, find

I'm using `find` in a bash script to clean up some cached files more than a day old:

```
find /tmp/my_files_*.cache -mtime +1 -delete
```

The problem is if the command matches no files it fails which prevents the rest of the script from running:

```
find: `/tmp/my_files_*.cache': No such file or directory
```

I'm currently working around it by appending `|| true` to the command but this is suboptimal as the error still appears in the output and it allows the script to continue past any other error that `find` might throw.

How can I tell `find` that it's OK if no files match?

Comment: How are you detecting the error ?

Comment: Take a look at the answer here http://serverfault.com/questions/540460/find-how-to-not-have-errors-stderr-when-no-files-exists basically you do a file count and if it isn't 0 you run the find and delete, if it is 0 you move on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your original command, it's not actually `find` that fails to match anything but your shell.

Ie, when you run

```
find /tmp/my_files_*.cache -mtime +1 -delete
```

If there were matching files, the shell's globbing functionality expanded that wildcard and the actual `find` invocation would look something like:

```
find /tmp/my_files_1.cache /tmp/my_files_2.cache /tmp/my_files_3.cache -mtime +1 -delete
```

(this could easily become a *very* long command, which in some cases can be a problem in itself)

When there are no matches, the wildcard is passed as-is, so the `find` invocation would look like:

```
find /tmp/my_files_*.cache -mtime +1 -delete
```

and behaving like most programs `find` does not do any sort of wildcard expansion on its own for the path argument(s), so it tries to find a file/directory that is literally named `/tmp/my_files_*.cache`, hence the error.

As was pointed out by Ipor Sircer, the more idiomatic way of using `find` is to instead give it the base path(s) and let `find` itself look through the directory contents and apply filters as needed.

Something like this should match what you were trying to do:

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name "my_files_*.cache" -mtime +1 -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find /tmp -name "*.cache" -mtime +1 -delete
```

Comment: Ah nice, because `/tmp` always exists it doesn't complain if the `name` filter reduces the matched set to zero.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that while this is proper use of `find` it's not an equivalent command to what the question was about. `find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -name "my_files_*.cache" -mtime +1 -delete` would actually do what the command in the question attempted to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not care whether there are any files to delete or not then don't bother to test for the success or not, just throw away any error:

find /tmp/my_files_*.cache -mtime +1 -delete 2> /dev/null